# Style Only Underline

Tags: css, underline

I have a header that is underlined using `text-decoration: underline;` The only problem is the line is too thin. I would like to make only the underline thicker. I have considered using `border-bottom` to do this but the border stretches the full width of the container and the text is centered. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap the text with `<span>` tags around, using `display: inline-block;`, remove `text-decoration: underline;` property and add `border-bottom: 2px solid #000;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQ6BK/)

> Note: Why use `inline-block`? So that you can also control the spacing
>   between the `border` and the text, using `padding` or `margins`, but if you don't require
>   `display: inline-block;` you can simply get rid of it as [NullPoiиteя](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417668/style-only-underline/17417700#comment25295855_17417700) said. Also, be sure to use a class on the parent element to select particular `span` tag of a particular `element.class` pair.

Comment: +1 its also looking fine without inline block http://jsfiddle.net/vpqZX/ .. but inline-block thing is really helpful too

Comment: @NullPoiиteя It will but I also provided a specific reason that `inline-block;` will give him a better control over that text :)

Answer (score 2):

Long ago, there was the property [`text-underline-width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-text-20030514/#text-decoration-width) in the CSS3 Text Module CR, defined to specify the thickness. However, it was not implemented in browsers, and it was dropped in the 2005 version of the module. This indirectly shows that it is not possible to set the underline width in CSS.

As regards to using `border-bottom` instead of a `text-decoration: underline`, it’s a different property, with different effect (the border is in an essentially lower position), and there are many existing questions on how to make it just as narrow as the text, which seems to be the issue here. But the simplest way is to use some inline (text-level) markup that spans the text in your heading, e.g.

```
<h1><u>Your heading text</u></h1>
```

with e.g.

```
u { text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 0.2em solid }
```

Instead of `u`, you could use e.g. the `span` element, but `u` has the advantage of producing at least a simple underline even when CSS styling is disabled in the browser. Using `u`, you of course need to switch off its default underlining, to avoid getting both underline and bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

try this style

```
  <h1 style="border-bottom: 5px solid black">This is heading 1</h1>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ganesh2java/BQ6BK/1/)

Comment: This is what I did do and as I said in my question it stretched the full width of the container.